# BootStrap Nav Bar issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Hi Everyone I am having a navbar issue with my website. The navbar covers the content. I looked around and a lot of people how seemed to get the fix below to work for them. My problem is it does edit the margins, but my nav bar moves with it as well. I can't figure out a way to only move the content and not the navbar.

```
/* fix fixed-bar */
body { padding-top: 40px; }
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
body { padding-top: 40px; }
}

/* fix fixed-bar jumping to in-page anchor issue */
*[id]:before {
display: block;
content: " ";
margin-top: -75px;
height: 75px;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you need a link to site.

Comment: Please make a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or supply us with a link

Comment: please add **position:relative;** to your class and replace margin-top with top... plus a jsFiddle in those scenarios is a MUST

Comment: wasdleagues.com is the url also I am just using body { padding-top: 70px; } right now. That code screws up other margins.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a class in css , and then put all the content inside a div label establishing that div  with that class, like this :

**CSS:**

```
.contentclass{
    /*your customized properties here
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="contentclass">
   <!--your content here-->
</div>
```

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: I fixed it by taking navbar css and adding it separately from the body. Thank you helping me.